# Cannot find layout

Tags: page-layout, package.xml, work-order

I am trying to retrieve a layout in FSL through package.xml from the Work Order object but the layout cannot be found.

I tried retrieving using this:

```
<types>
    <members>WorkOrder-FSL Work Order Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name
</types>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this? Thanks.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the org browser on your vs code to find and retrieve the page layout.
Some common mistakes which can lead to this error

- Incorrect object api name
- Incorrect Page Layout name (missing a space etc)
- Incoorect org authenticated on VS code.

Also, can you try this?
Create a Project with Manifest
In the package.xml, specify the layouts (make sure you have it in package.xml), example as below:

*
Layout

Execute SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org

User-added image

Or you can use sfdx commands

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Layout